# QtConcurrent::run - handling crash

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm executing one function in a separate thread from QtConcurrent::run. If one computation within that function hangs/crashes (it is a call to external library) my whole application is not-responsive/crashes. Is there a way to handle this (catch the crash)? Unfortunately the external dll does not throw any exceptions.

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::update);

void MyClass::update()
{   
    while(!simulationDone())
    {
       //call to external lib
       simulationDone = externalCompute();
    }
 }
```

Comment: crashes are often the result of undefined behavior and as such you can't be sure of anything after it triggers

Comment: To recover from crashing code, you’d need to move that code to another process, not just another thread.

Comment: I reimplemented my code so that now my class inherits QThread. Update() method was moved to run(). This of course crashes too, but it does not hang the application.